# Cypress runner loading mobile site instead of desktop site

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, web-testing

I am opening the website `https://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/nl` with `cy.visit()`.

However, the cypress runner is opening the mobile website instead of the desktop website.

Any ideas why and how to change this behavior?

Comment: Does the website try to detect the size of e.g. your browser window? Maybe try changing the viewport? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport#Syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile setting seem to be more like tablet size settings.

You can control the viewport before visiting

```js
it('opens van gogh', () => {
  cy.viewport(1800,1000)
  cy.visit('https://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/nl');    // large screen layout
});
```

If you open devtools to the right and resize, you will see the breakpoint is around 1025 px wide.

Cypress viewport defaults to 1000 px, so you get the small-screen layout.

---

If you look at one of the `<article>` elements, it has breakpoint styling of

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 64em)
```

which equates to 1024px for the default pixel size of 16px.